# scheme recursion - power of an int

Tags: scheme

I am trying to implement a function that tells if the parameter is power of 2. Here is what I have

```
   (define (powof2 x) (cond  
   [(and (even? x) (> x 1)) ((powof2 (/ x 2)))] 
   [else (equal?(x 1))]))
```

But when I try to run it with parameter 12 I get the error saying: 
Error: 3 is not a function [powof2, powof2, powof2, (anon)]

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah those parenthesis ;-)

```
(define (powof2 x)
  (cond  
    [(and (even? x) (> x 1)) (powof2 (/ x 2))]
    [else (= x 1)]))
```

Note that in the 3rd line and 4th line you had an extra pair of parenthesis, and in the 4th line that you should use `=` to compare numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I see it now

Comment: I see that you have never accepted answers to your questions. Maybe it's a good idea to do so if you think that your question has been completely answered.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, just realized that